# Is it possible for a transformator to ignore XML markup errors?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to use XSLT to transform a XML-file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
     <stuff>Her we have some text and some false markup like <this> and so on</stuff>    
</row>
```

If I start the transformation, I will get an error that there is no end tag for "this". Is there any possibility to bypass this?

Comment: It depends on the environment, usually an XSLT processor relies on an underlying XML parser and such an XML parser will simply report that malformed XML before the XSLT processor does its work. On the other hand on some platforms there are APIs (SAX, XmlReader) that might allow you to plug in your own parser that would then correct the mistake and present the XSLT processor the right way of events to be able to transform the input. But you haven't in any indicated which platform you use, nor what you expect to happen with the unclosed `this` element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using oXygen and Saxon6.5.5 as transformator. The problem is, that sometimes there is only the "<" charakter. Like "2 < 4" or smilies "<:". So I dont really want to change any of the text.

Comment: Well, as a I said, you need to plug in a parser that parses the malformed input you have according to the rules you want it to use to present that input to the XSLT processor, in the case of Java you could for instance write your own SAX parser that then is able to create the SAX events (e.g.characters for `2 < 4`) you want that to represent. But the rules have to be clear to clearly implement that and writing such a parser is also not an easy task. You could also check whether the various HTML tag soup parsers give you useful result, even if that input is not HTML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen So maybe I should approach the problem earlier, before the XML-file is generated. Lets say I change all "<" in something like "asdf", then I generate the XML-file, transform and then change the "asdf" back in "<"? How is this normally done?

Comment: My advice would to avoid generating that malformed markup in the beginning and instead ensure that well-formed XML is generated from the start, there are lots of APIs and tools, including XSLT, XQuery, the various DOM/XOM/JDOM, that help you achieve that. Fixing something that in some parts is XML and in other parts is not is not possible with pure XML tools, as I said, the various JSoup/HTML TagSoup parsers might be a starting point to parse markup with less strict rules than XML, but integrating them or even adapting them is not something that fits into a comment on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention oXygen I think you are in a position to use XSLT 2 or 3 with Saxon 9. In that case you could try whether David Carlisle's tag soup parser https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl written in pure XSLT 2 gives you the parsing result you need.

I have made an example with the last of your two examples

```
    <root>
        <paragraph>Is 3 < 4?</paragraph>
        <paragraph>XSLT is powerful <:</paragraph>
    </root>
```

in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFc, the full stylesheet is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math d"
    version="3.0">


    <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:param name="mal-formed-markup" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[
        <root>
            <paragraph>Is 3 < 4?</paragraph>
            <paragraph>XSLT is powerful <:</paragraph>
        </root>
    ]]></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="d:htmlparse($mal-formed-markup, '', false())"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it parses that into

```
    <root>
        <paragraph>Is 3 &lt; 4?</paragraph>
        <paragraph>XSLT is powerful &lt;:</paragraph>
    </root>
```

so for those two examples that parser might fix your markup as desired and in your real application you could of course load any non XML file as you have with `unparsed-text` and then feed that returned string to the `d:htmlparse` function, instead of using the data included in the XSLT as a CDATA section as I have done for the example.

Another option is an oXygen user that offers the commercial editions of Saxon 9 to you is to use the extension function http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/parse-html.html.

But the best advice is to fix the generation of the input to use XML tools so that the input is XML from the beginning.