# XSLT disable-output-escaping but allow some entities

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xss

I have the following xslt to output comments but it is vulnerable to XSS if I disable all output escaping.

```
   <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//datafor:field[datafor:name='comments']/datafor:value" />
```

How can I allow only the following html attributes so that I can retain some formating in the rendered output?

```
'b,strong,i,ul,ol,li,p,br,p[style]',div,div[class]'
```

Comment: I would consider parsing that stuff as HTML (text/html) (using an extension function of your XSLT 2 processor or David Carlisle's HTML tag soup parser done in XSLT 2) and then process the created (X)HTML with templates that ensure you strip/remove the stuff you don't want and keep the stuff (e.g. `b`, `strong`, .. elements) you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen is there an example of this?

Comment: Well, it all depends on the processor you use, I have added an answer for SaxonJS in the browser, for Saxon Java or .NET check whether you use PE or EE which has some extension function `saxon:parse-html` or use the named HTML XSLT 2 parser, there are various examples here on StackOverflow e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734846/is-it-possible-for-a-transformator-to-ignore-xml-markup-errors/50736799#50736799

Comment: @MartinHonnen  I won't be able to use the SaxonJS example due to restrictions on vendors application. Is there an example using David Carlisle's HTML parser?

Comment: Well, I did already link to one example using the parser, of course that example doesn't do exactly what you want here but simply copies the parsed HTML but the stylesheet in the answer with David's parser instead of the call into JavaScript is kind of what you need/can do, i.e. parse the HTML fragment and push it through a mode that only outputs the elements and attributes you want to be output.

Answer (score 1):

Or, using SaxonJS, in the browser, you could call into JavaScript to parse the HTML fragment and process it e.g.

```js
function parseHTML(html) {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
}

const xml = `<orders>
  <order>
    <id>o1</id>
    <date>2022-06-12</date>
    <comments><![CDATA[I want the following extras: <ol>
      <li>32 GB RAM</li>
      <li>1000 GB SSD</li>
    ]]></comments>
  </order>
</orders>`;

const xslt = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode name="html"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="html" match="b | strong | i | ul | ol | li | p | br | p | div | p/@style | div/@class" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="orders">
    <h1>Orders</h1>
    <xsl:where-populated>
      <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ol>
    </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="order">
    <li>Order {id} from {format-date(date, '[D] [M] [Y0000]')}
    <div>
      <h2>Comments</h2>
      <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="js:parseHTML(string(comments))" mode="html"/>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(map {
  'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
  'source-node' : parse-xml($xml)
  }
)?output/*/*/node()`,
  [],
  { params : {
      xslt: xslt,
      xml: xml
    }
  }
);

document.body.append(...result);
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/js/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
```

With the [XSLT implementation of an HTML tag soup parser by David Carlisle](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl) it would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
  xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:mode name="html"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="html" match="b | strong | i | ul | ol | li | p | br | p | div | p/@style | div/@class" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="orders">
    <h1>Orders</h1>
    <xsl:where-populated>
      <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ol>
    </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="order">
    <li>Order {id} from {format-date(date, '[D] [M] [Y0000]')}
    <div>
      <h2>Comments</h2>
      <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="d:htmlparse(comments)" mode="html"/>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online sample](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Ad%3D%22data%3A%2Cdpc%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aimport%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdavidcarlisle%2Fweb-xslt%2Fraw%2Fmain%2Fhtmlparse%2Fhtmlparse.xsl%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%20html-version%3D%225.0%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20name%3D%22html%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20mode%3D%22html%22%20match%3D%22b%20%7C%20strong%20%7C%20i%20%7C%20ul%20%7C%20ol%20%7C%20li%20%7C%20p%20%7C%20br%20%7C%20p%20%7C%20div%20%7C%20p%2F%40style%20%7C%20div%2F%40class%22%20xpath-default-namespace%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%20mode%3D%22%23current%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20mode%3D%22html%22%20match%3D%22script%22%20xpath-default-namespace%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ETest%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22orders%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EOrders%3C%2Fh1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhere-populated%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Col%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fol%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhere-populated%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22order%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EOrder%20%7Bid%7D%20from%20%7Bformat-date%28date%2C%20%27%5BD%5D%20%5BM%5D%20%5BY0000%5D%27%29%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch2%3EComments%3C%2Fh2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22d%3Ahtmlparse%28comments%29%22%20mode%3D%22html%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Corders%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Corder%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cid%3Eo1%3C%2Fid%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdate%3E2022-06-12%3C%2Fdate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccomments%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BI%20want%20the%20following%20extras%3A%20%3Col%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E32%20GB%20RAM%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E1000%20GB%20SSD%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27test%27%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fcomments%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Forder%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Forders%3E&input-type=XML).

The current samples copy only the listed elements but copy any text node through, if elements like e.g. `script` need to be completely stripped add an empty template `<xsl:template mode="html" match="script" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>`.

Of course, consider to download the HTML parser module and xsl:import a local file for your own application instead of pulling from github.

Comment: trying to test your example but it doesn't seem to work when I enter the above xml/xslt into https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html. The link to your online sample doesn't work either?

Comment: @adam78, I am afraid I don't know about that freeformatter.com you seem to want to use, get in touch with the people who run that to find out whether they support XSLT 3 and xsl:import. As for my online sample at https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/, I just tried the link from the answer in Google Chrome, the link was opened, I hit the "transform" button and the transformation was run and the result was shown without any problems.

Comment: I think it because in your example your using mode which is only supported in xslt 3 and I'm stuck with xslt 2. Is there a way to achieve the same without using modes?

Comment: Modes are part of XSLT 1 and 2 so have e.g. `xsl:template mode="..."` or `xsl:apply-templates mode="..."` shouldn't pose any problems. You can remove the `xsl:mode` declaration, I think. You will need to also remove the `xsl:where-populated` as being XSLT 3 and replace the use of text value templates in e.g. `Order {id} from {format-date(date, '[D] [M] [Y0000]')}` with `xsl:value-of` e.g. `Order <xsl:value-of select="id"/> from <xsl:value-of select="format-date(date, '[D] [M] [Y0000]')"/>`.

Comment: I've notice if my html markup is as follow `<comments><![CDATA[<div id="123" class="myclass">Some comment</div>]]></comments>` then I get error: An attribute node (class) cannot be created after a child of the containing element. I take it's because I have id attribute before the class attribute in the div. How can I fix that without changing the html?

Comment: @adam, consider to ask that as a new question with the necessary details of minimal but complete samples, output you want, error you get, XSLT processor you use.

Comment: @adam78, part of the problem might be that the code in the answer is probably not good at handling elements with more than one attribute, at least, if that attribute is not listed in the explicit match pattern. So you can add e.g. `<xsl:template mode="html" match="@id | b | strong | i | ul | ol | li | p | br | p | div | p/@style | div/@class" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` and I think the error goes away and the `id` attribute is copied or `<xsl:template match="@id" mode="html"/>` and the `id` attribute is removed and you don't get an error either.

Comment: so I'd have to include every attribute that could appear in the markup. Is there anyway to define the pattern to allow divs with a class attribute regardless of what other attribute are defined in the div?

Comment: Well, you can use `@*` in that match pattern that copies nodes and add those you don't want to the empty template. But I think the main problem is that the original answer is doing what you asked for with that particular example, the solution relies on the built-in templates by not declaring anything for the named mode `html`, and unfortunately those default templates are a bit odd by not copying attributes attributes but instead output attribute values as text nodes. So that way with two attributes and no match pattern explicitly treating one of them, the attribute is output as a text node.

Comment: That way the solution is probably not generic enough, either try to fix it with `@*` in the template copying nodes or ask a new question, I don't think it makes sense to try to resolve that here in further comments.